# Can I get SASS to function like Chrome Dev Tools and update in realtime without saving?

Tags: google-chrome, sass

OK, so I have recently switched to Middleman with SASS, HAML and CoffeeScript to speed up my UI design workflow. I am using livereload to speed it up even further. However, I still miss one feature of the Chrome Dev. Tools. When you edit the CSS in Dev. Tools, it updates instantly, making it great for doing all those little pixel-perfect tweaks that we love so much.

In Middleman with livereload, of course, this functionality can be had by simply saving the file. Maybe I'm being whiny, but hitting ctrl-s each time can add up quick. I'm wondering if someone knows of a way to get the functionality of being able to edit SASS in realtime without hitting save after each change.

Comment: Err, as far as I know, this feature isn't built-in to Chrome at all, are you using something like [chrome-devtools-autosave](https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave)?

Comment: You can implement something similar in your text editor (on ; or ↩ depending on syntax). Example implementation for sass in Sublime Text 2: https://gist.github.com/1859420

Comment: Hey, thanks Jamie, this is sort of what I was looking for but not really. Probably as close as I can get right now though.

Answer (score -1):

There is a save extension for Chrome DevTools that can help you.
http://code.google.com/p/devtools-save/downloads/list?

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, because what is being edited in Chrome is the compiled CSS, not the SASS. Still cool though, thanks.